# Force device orientation

Tags: javascript, screen-orientation

is there any way to rotate screen on the desktop with javascript?
Something like accessing screen.rotation API and change the rotation/orientation?

I'm aware of the CSS transform property. but that's not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You can do it in the developer tools I think, but not from JavaScript.

Comment: https://usefulangle.com/post/105/javascript-change-screen-orientation Check this out. It works only on mobile.

Comment: @Bergi Yes. most modern browsers do have the developer tools, device/responsive tools. But looking for a javascript solution, if there is any.

Comment: @pasanjg yea, but in this case is desktop.